# html how to show a hidden list on hover?

Tags: html, css

what I want is the list of products, mac, iPhone & ipad to show when hover, over the products, 
but it won't do it.

> HTML

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">COMPANY</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="lastitem">
      <a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">MAC</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">iPHONE</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">iPAD</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
li ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

li:hover ul {
  left-side: auto;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yeh that markup looks all kinds of messed up. Save your save a headache and look at boostrap

Comment: change `li :hover` to `li:hover`, the space shouldn't be there. also what is `left-side: auto`?

Comment: And `left: auto` `instead of left-side: auto`

Comment: Thanks that, changing left-side to left solved it.

Answer (score 2):

here: Just hide the list of products and on hover use the ~ to target the element that you need to affect
http://jsfiddle.net/1fdcbwvL/1/

```
<div>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">COMPANY</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="lastitem">
        <a id="products" href="">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul id="product-list">
            <li><a href="">MAC</a></li>
            <li><a href="">iPHONE</a></li>
            <li><a href="">iPAD</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSSS

```
 #product-list{
    display:none;
}
#products:hover ~ #product-list{
    display:block;
}

#product-list:hover{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: The problem is - you can't hover on iphone, mac or ipad.

Comment: the hover will trigger as you touch

Comment: @makshh you can't hover on a Mac?

Comment: I mean try to click on the product MAC :) in this code

Comment: then you just add `#product-list:hover{
    display:block;
}` I will update the example for you